# DAX - Creating a measure in power BI which ignores all filters except one

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to write a measure called Items Per Lift, which is calculated as follows:

Count of Report Items / Count of Lifts

I have a Line and Stacked Column chart, where this measure will be used. It currently shows the number of Report Items per engineer on the bars. I want to add a line which uses the above measure. I want to make sure that the denominator side of the measure (the right hand side) always uses the number of lifts per engineer in total, and never gets filtered further than that. The numerator (left side) of measure can be filtered depending on slicers selected on the page, etc

The data is contained in two tables, 'Insurance Matrix' and 'ANSAPBILifts'. ANSAPBILifts contains 8016 rows in total. The data in each table is as follows:

Insurance Matrix - contains all Report Items

```
Report Item          SiteIDLine
1                    1212
2                    1212
3                    1256
4                    1443
```

ANSAPBILifts - contains a list of all lifts with engineer assigned to each lift:

```
SiteIDLine           Engineer ID
1212                 MRob
1256                 MRob
1443                 PCli
1554                 PCli
1599                 AKen
```

So the measure should always contain 2 on the denominator side for engineer MRob, it should always be 2 for engineer PCli, and it should always be 1 for engineer AKen, etc

I wrote the following for the measure originally:

```
Items per Lift = divide(count('Insurance Matrix'[Report Item]),(COUNT(ANSAPBILifts[SiteIDLine])))
```

However, both the numerator and denominator would always get filtered with this measure.

So I then used:

```
Items per LiftALL = divide(count('Insurance Matrix'[Report Item]),CALCULATE(COUNT(ANSAPBILifts[SiteIDLine]),ALLEXCEPT(ANSAPBILifts,ANSAPBILifts[Engineer ID])))
```

However, this results in the same measure as the first attempt, ie both sides of the measure are filtered if any slicers are used on the page.

At this point I am a bit confused as to what to try next. If anyone can help it would be very appreciated

See below chart with data, no filters applied on this chart, the measure is correct at this point:

[image]

See below chart with data, some filters have been applied on this page, the measure is now incorrect at this point, the denominator has now changed but I need it to remain the same:

[image]

Comment: check out the dax formatter: https://www.daxformatter.com/ or even better https://www.sqlbi.com/tools/dax-studio/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got this to work, using the following:

```
Items per LiftALL = divide(count('Insurance Matrix'[Report Item]),
    CALCULATE(COUNT(ANSAPBILifts[SiteIDLine]),ALLEXCEPT(ANSAPBILifts,ANSAPBILifts[Engineer ID]),
        ALL('Insurance Matrix'[Status],'Insurance Matrix'[Technical Markup ])))
```

Thanks for everyones help!

Answer (score 3):

When I understand you correctly, you want to override the slicers, but only on the denominator side of this measure:

```
Items per Lift =
DIVIDE (
    COUNT ( 'Insurance Matrix'[Report Item] ),
    ( COUNT ( ANSAPBILifts[SiteIDLine] ) )
)
```

Try using the ALL function on the slicer columns. Like so:

```
Items per Lift =
DIVIDE (
    COUNT ( 'Insurance Matrix'[Report Item] ),
    (
        CALCULATE (
            COUNT ( ANSAPBILifts[SiteIDLine] ),
            ALL ( 'Insurance Matrix'[Status], 'Insurance Matrix'[Technical Markup ] )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: That didnt work, it was still returning filtered rows on both numerator and denominator

Comment: It does work! Put the denominator part in a separate Card visual and you will see. Like this: `Liftcount = CALCULATE (
            COUNT ( ANSAPBILifts[SiteIDLine] ),
            ALL ( 'Insurance Matrix'[Status], 'Insurance Matrix'[Technical Markup ] )`